# Create summary table in R using statistics from package `modifiedmk`

Tags: r, group-by, statistics, pivot, summary

I'm trying to run a function from the `modifiedmk` package in R.

```
install.packages('modifiedmk')
library(modifiedmk)
```

I have a dataframe `data` which I produced with the following:

```
Station <- c('APT','APT', 'APT','APT', 'APT', 'APT', 'APT','APT', 'APT','APT','APT','APT',
              'AF','AF', 'AF','AF','AF','AF','AF','AF','AF',
             'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL', 'EL',
             'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS', 'GFS'
              )
Rainfall <- c(375.3, 263.3, 399.2, 242.6, 847.6, 276.5, 712.8, 366.3, 188.6, 478.4, 539, 682.5,
            520.7, 1337.8, 524, 908.4,748.5,411.8, 772.4,978.5,983,
            732.4, 788.6, 567.1, 576, 931.6, 727.2, 1079.3, 902.8,493.4,  630.7, 784.1,660.2, 531.3, 487.1,798.4,
            1064.1,  590.3, 1011.2, 1037.1,  1398.4, 1153.6,994.1,  1100.2,743.7,637.4, 792.2, 891.9,880.9, 670, 920.2,681.4)
Year <- c('1957','1958','1959','1960','1961','1962','1963','1964','1965','1966','1967','1968',
                  '1960','1961','1962','1963','1964','1965','1966','1967','1968',
                  '1957','1958','1959','1960','1961','1962','1963','1964','1965','1966','1967','1968','1969','1970','1971',
                  '1964','1965','1966','1967','1968','1969','1970','1971','1972','1973','1974','1975','1976','1977','1978','1979')
length(Year)
data<-data.frame(Year, Station, Rainfall)
```

where I have four `Stations` of rainfall data as rows in the dataframe. I want to apply the `mmky1lag` method from the `modifiedmk` package on each `Station` of data and produce a summary table in R that has two columns:

1. The percent of stations with significant trends where p < 0.05
2. The average Sen's slope

For example, I can run the `mmky1lag` method on all of the Rainfall data using `mmky1lag(as.vector(data$Rainfall))` which produces

```
> mmky1lag(as.vector(data$Rainfall))
Corrected Zc  new P-value         N/N*   Original Z  old P.value 
3.332353e+00 8.611480e-04 1.297360e+00 3.795608e+00 1.472822e-04 
         Tau  Sen's slope old.variance new.variance 
3.634992e-01 9.092857e+00 1.605933e+04 2.083474e+04
```

And I'm interested in two of those outputs:

Column 1:

```
# Get percent of stations with significant trends where p < 0.05
mmky1lag(as.vector(data$Rainfall))[2] < 0.05
```

and Column 2:

```
# Make another column that is the mean Sen's slope
mmky1lag(as.vector(data$Rainfall))[7]
```

However, how do I apply this method on `data` where I get a result for each individual `Station`? In python, I would groupby `Station` and then apply the method. But I'm not sure how to do that in R.

Then after grouping by station, I want a summary table with the two aforementioned columns of information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the `mmky1lag` function to a data frame by group (in this case, `station`) there are multiple approaches to consider.

First, you could use `aggregate`:

```
library(modifiedmk)

mktests <- aggregate(Rainfall ~ Station, data = data, FUN = mmky1lag)
```

This will take a formula using the measure of `Rainfall` by `Station` group. All of your results will be returned in a matrix with the MK test parameters in a single column.

Another approach might be with `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

mktests <- as.data.table(data)[, as.list(mmky1lag(Rainfall)), by = Station]
```

This will take the results from `mmky1lag` and put into a list and then converted to a data table. The option `by` will allow you to perform this by `Station`.

A third approach might be with `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

mktests <- data %>%
  group_by(Station) %>%
  group_map(~mmky1lag(.x$Rainfall)) %>%
  setNames(unique(sort(data$Station))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "Station")
```

This uses `group_by` to group by `Station`, and then `group_map` which will apply the `mmky1lag` function to grouped elements. The `setNames` is needed to add `Station` value back to the results, and then `bind_rows` to turn the resultant list into a data frame.

The result (with the `data.table` solution) should look like this (the other approaches should be similar):

```
R> mktests
   Station Corrected Zc new P-value      N/N* Original Z old P.value        Tau Sen's slope old.variance new.variance
1:     APT    1.2801214   0.2005025 0.4849366  0.8914431   0.3726915  0.2121212    17.32083     212.6667    103.12986
2:      AF    1.2424858   0.2140574 0.5703144  0.9383149   0.3480826  0.2777778    29.73750      92.0000     52.46892
3:      EL   -0.7452428   0.4561249 1.1288325 -0.7917947   0.4284804 -0.1619048    -9.60000     408.3333    460.93994
4:     GFS   -1.3242038   0.1854354 1.4160741 -1.5757881   0.1150746 -0.3000000   -19.65333     493.3333    698.59657
```

If you want the percentage of `Station`s with p < .05, you could do:

```
sum(mktests$`new P-value` < .05) / nrow(mktests)
```

In this case, it is zero as none of them were significant based on `new P-value`.

The mean of `Sen's slope` can be computed:

```
mean(mktests$`Sen's slope`)
4.45125
```

I'm not sure if you anticipated different results with your example data (as you suggested the results would be put into 2 columns). Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: How do we now that the names are assigned in the same order as in the list elements using ```setNames```? Does ```group_by``` always order in alphabetical order? Please clarify

Comment: @RamakrishnaS That is my understanding, and has been discussed in prior github issues (such as [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3279)). After `group_by` the results are alphabetized, and we need `unique` and `sort` so the results match with `setNames`. Another [github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4531) discusses retaining names after `group_map` - but right now the list returned is unnamed. `purrr:map` after `nest` may be an alternative...

Answer (score 2):

You can try do do something like this, in base R. 
First, you can have your data as a list, and each element is one `Station`:

```
data_list <- split(data,data$Station)
```

Then you can use `lapply()`, quoting from [the doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply):

> lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which
> is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X.

```
library(modifiedmk)
stat_list <- lapply(data_list, function(x) mmky1lag(x$Rainfall))
```

Now, you can put as `data.frame` for example, and then calculate what you need.
You can use `do.call()` to apply `rbind()` to the list, and put it in a `data.frame()`. Generally I prefere work with the names of the columns instead of their index, but this is subjective.
From [the doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cbind) `rbind()`:

> Take a sequence of vector, matrix or data-frame arguments and combine
> by columns or rows, respectively. These are generic functions with
> methods for other R classes.

From [the doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/do.call) `do.call()`:

> do.call constructs and executes a function call from a name or a
> function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

```
stat_df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, stat_list))
```

Now you can easily calculate what you need:

```
# percentage of the < 0.05 p-values
# here you calculate the number of row of the subset of interest of the
# df / number of row of the dataset.
nrow(stat_df[stat_df$new.P.value < 0.05,])/nrow(stat_df)*100
[1] 0

# Or if you want a prettier result printed:
library(formattable)
percent(nrow(stat_df[stat_df$new.P.value < 0.05,])/nrow(stat_df))
[1] 0.00%

# the mean of Sen.s.slope
mean(stat_df$Sen.s.slope)
[1] 4.45125
```

Also, I do not get the way you'd like the desired output, it's written Column1 and Column2. If you define it, it's possible to have a result that fits better to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Does this come close? The percentage would be zero, as all p-values are bigger than 5%. You'd need to add the `< 0.05` in the loop to get a true/false value in the data frame.

```
results <- data.frame(matrix(NA, 4, 3))
colnames(results) <- c('station', 'p-val', 'Sen-slope')
for(ii in seq_along(unique(Station))){
  i <- unique(Station)[ii]
  results[ii, 1] <- i
  results[ii, 2] <- mmky1lag(as.vector(data$Rainfall[data$Station %in% i]))[2]
  results[ii, 3] <- mmky1lag(as.vector(data$Rainfall[data$Station %in% i]))[7]
}

> results
  station     p-val Sen-slope
1     APT 0.2005025  17.32083
2      AF 0.2140574  29.73750
3      EL 0.4561249  -9.60000
4     GFS 0.1854354 -19.65333
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use tidyverse it is easy to do pandas-like syntax.

```
# Importing tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# Calculating grouped values
data %>%
  group_by(Station) %>%
  summarise('p-value' = mmky1lag(Rainfall)[2]<0.05, "Sen's slope" = mmky1lag(Rainfall)[7])

# Output
Station p.value Sen.s.slope
AF      FALSE    29.73750
APT     FALSE    17.32083
EL      FALSE    -9.60000
GFS     FALSE   -19.65333
```